# CSS Setting height based on % width with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

The page in question is essentially a grid of images, always three across no matter the size of the window.

The images are coming from Wordpress posts, and each one has its own container div with overflow:hidden. The container divs are set in css to width 33.33%. I am using jQuery on ready() and window resize to set the height of the container divs equal to their width.

The html/php structure looks like this:

```
<div class="collectionPostContainer">
                    <div class="collectionImageHolder">
                        <img src='<?php the_field('photo'); ?>'/>
                    </div>
</div>
```

The js function looks like this:

```
  function resizeEntryHeight(){
windowWidth = $(window).width();
$('.collectionPostContainer').each(function(){
    $(this).css('height',$(this).width()+'');
});
```

}

The problem is that when the page first loads, the first four entries each get assigned a slightly higher height than the following entries, throwing off the grid at the third row. As soon as I call the function in the console or on window resize again, the heights get fixed and are all equal.

Tested on Firefox and Chrome, at multiple starting window sizes. Oddly, the first four entries always get a height exactly 5px higher than the later entries.

So I am wondering why elements with ostensibly the same width are being assigned different heights within the same loop, and how I can make my pretty image grid.

Hope this is clear!

Thanks.

Comment: you never uses windowWidth

Comment: windowWidth gets used in a different function for something else.

Comment: can you provide some fiddle so we can exactly know what is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this jquery plugin: https://github.com/karacas/imgLiquid

Comment: Interesting, but it looks like this is for making an image fit its container. I am already doing that just fine, it's the containers themselves that are getting a strange initial size.

Answer (score 0):

This must work for you

```
var resizeEntryHeight=function(){
$('.collectionPostContainer').each(function(){
    $(this).css('height',$(this).width()+'px');
});
}

$(document).ready(function(){
resizeEntryHeight();
$(window).resize(resizeEntryHeight());
});
```

Comment: It's not shown in my code here, but I am already calling resizeEntryHeight() at $(document).ready(), and at $(window).resize().